# react-native-modalbox crashes react native app without error log

Tags: android, react-native

When a button is clicked to open the modal, it works for the first time. Upon the second attempt, the app crashes without any error log.

React Native version: 0.61

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to place the `Modal` tag as a child component in the `KeyboardAvoidingView` and not otherwise.

like so:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView>
  <Text> Please upvote! </Text>
  <Modal ... >
  </Modal>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

This worked for me.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Modal does not open with this solution

Comment: @parvdesai Do you have useRef() initialized and assigned to that modal?. Kindly share your code so I can assist.